# Stop creation of chome file created in target folder in karate?

Tags: karate

While executing the UI test in karate a chrome file got created in the target folder which consumes a lot of space as I am working on the virtual machine that reflects into the cost of the machine So anyhow is it possible to stop the creation of that file as I have to manually delete those files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your feedback we've just added a `userDataDir` option to the driver config.

Please see commit for details:

https://github.com/intuit/karate/commit/0af1ba16f66ef8d1f700edb3bf1f4ba55c865f00

So you can do this:

```
* configure driver = { type: 'chrome', userDataDir: 'target/chrome-user-dir' }
```

You can even set it to `null` in which case Chrome will use system defaults.

Please follow the instructions here and confirm this works, in which case we can expedite a release: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Developer-Guide

Comment: I tried it but it's still creating those chrome files in my target directory
@peter

Comment: @Ninja it is time for you to contribute code please

Answer (score 3):

The karate 0.95 version, uses a hardcoded way to define it on [DriverOptions.java](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/6de466bdcf105d72450a40cf31b8adb5c043037d/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/driver/DriverOptions.java#L170).
So passing this settings to karate, don't work.
Because [Chrome.java](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/6de466bdcf105d72450a40cf31b8adb5c043037d/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/driver/chrome/Chrome.java#L59) `options.arg("--user-data-dir=" + options.workingDirPath)` don't catch it.

So, I just created a batch file to start chrome with my settings, before calling karate.

Add it to your feature, to avoid chrome start:

```
* configure driver = { type: 'chrome', start: false }
```

This batch file call chrome with no wait style and call karate after it.
I delete my previous reports too.

Batch file:

```
cd %~dp0

SET PORT=9222
SET AGENT='Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) FxiOS/18.1 Mobile/16B92 Safari/605.1.15'
SET PROFILE="%~dp0\chrome"

DEL "%~dp0\target" /s /q

START "" /D "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\" chrome.exe "--remote-debugging-port=%PORT%" --no-first-run "--user-data-dir=%PROFILE%" --disable-popup-blocking --disable-infobars -–disable-notifications --disable-dev-shm-usage "--user-agent=%AGENT%"

java -jar karate.jar yourtest-01.feature
```

> **EDIT:**
> The development version 2.0.0, fixed it.
> Just add userDataDir to your configuration.
>
> To build follow instructions here:
> https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Developer-Guide#build
>
> Take a look for your own: [DriverOptions.java#L170](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/6dc6d281e9f9fe400da3feebe438b517f3f7d28a/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/driver/DriverOptions.java#L170)
>
> BTW, I issued a PR to fix when userDataDir is defined, workingDir keeps creating chrome folders with empty content!

Comment: great idea ! thanks for sharing. please suggest any changes to the defaults we should make to karate

Comment: Cool! I will fill a PR.